# Is there a way to install youcompleteme plugin using vim 8.0 default plugin manager?

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me

I read that vim 8 provides it default plugin manager. I upgraded my vim to vim 8.0 and am trying to install the plugin using the method provided in the documentation. youcompleteme plugin github repo recommends using Vundle to install the plugin on mac. Just wondering if it can also be installed using default plugin manager supported in vim 8.0 and how to install it?

Comment: Simply clone it into `~/.vim/pack/dist/start` if you want it always available, use the `opt` folder instead of start if you only need it on demand. (but then you need to execute `:packadd YouCompleteMe` whenever you want it to have it loaded). However YouCompleteMe needs some postinstallation script to be run, so you need to do that manually.

Answer (score 8):

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/pack/plugins/opt
git clone https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe ~/.vim/pack/plugins/opt/YouCompleteMe
cd ~/.vim/pack/plugins/opt/YouCompleteMe && git submodule update --init --recursive && ./install.py --all
```

add following code to your vimrc

```
execute 'packadd YouCompleteMe'
```

or execute

```
packadd YouCompleteMe
```

when you want to start it.

Comment: Did you test this? `packadd foo` looks for `pack/*/opt/foo`. See the section immediately *before* [`:h pack-add`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#pack-add) on how to add a single plugin using packages.

Comment: Also, the git clone command is not creating YouCompleteMe directory. But it did help anyway.